# API Controller with generic type c#

Tags: c#, api, blazor

I am new to API Controllers, c# Blazor etc. I am trying to develop a generic Web API controller with a sample function like this

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUowLookups UowLookups;

    public WeatherForecastController(IUowLookups uowLookups)
    {
        UowLookups = uowLookups;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get<TEntity>() where TEntity:Entity
    {
        var data = UowLookups.Repository<TEntity>().GetAll();
        return data;
    }
}
```

I want to call this API function from a Blazor client app. Is this doable? If yes how. I tried something like this but it's not even compiling.

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get<TEntity>()
    {
        var apiName = $"api/weatherforecast" ;
        Type typeParameterType = typeof(TEntity);
        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<TEntity>>
                (await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync(apiName, typeParameterType), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
    }
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting while compiling?

Comment: You can't pass generic parameters over the wire using `GetFromJsonAsync`, and furthermore, Web Api does not support the notion of having the client pass in generic type arguments to the method.  You appear to be misunderstanding what the second argument is intended for -- you can pass a `System.Type` _instead_ of passing in generic type arguments (`<IEnumerable<TEntity>>`), but not both, and in either case, it simply informs the _deserializer_ the type it should produce and does not transmit that information to the server.

Comment: Krik, Thank you for the quick response. Is there any way of achieving it? maybe by using some other functions

Comment: Hi Chetan, The error is Argument 1 cannot convert the object to system.io.stream. I assume the problem is as explained by Krik

Comment: @Jacob what is your motivation for wanting to do this vs. just creating a separate controller for each of your entity types?  Is it a simple matter of DRY (don't repeat yourself)?  IMO, this will ultimately be unmaintanable as you increase the sophistication of your controller (various transformations, permissions, etc. for different entity types).  I would strongly discourage you from this approach.

Comment: If you _really_ _really_ want to do this, you can pass the entity type as a query string argument and use reflection to parse that and turn it into a `System.Type` and then use that with `UowLookups.Repository` (which _hopefully_ has an overload that takes a `Type`).  However, since I don't know what `UowLookups` is (it doesn't appear to be Entity Framework) I can't provide more specific guidance.

Comment: Hi Kirk, Thankyou for your time in helping me. As mentioned, I consider myself a starter in c#.  We have more than 100 lookup/master tables(like products, Departments etc) as in our new project. 80% of these are just CRUD operations. We intend to follow the repository pattern and developed a generic repository according to our need. Repository<TEntity> is supposed to be passed to each controller. So I will end up creating 100 plus controllers just for the sake of passing my TEntity.

Comment: So  I was thinking to create a base controller and pass TEntity to this controller so that the base controller can perform the CRUD operation based on the passed TEntity. At present, I have to do the following

 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DepartmentsController : LookupBaseController<Department>
    {

        private readonly IUowLookups UowLookups;

        public DepartmentsController(IUowLookups uowLookups) : base(uowLookups)
        {
            UowLookups = uowLookups;
        }



    }